# Jquery comparing background color

Tags: jquery

I am using:

```
var element = $(this).parents("tr:first");

if (element.css("background-color")=="black)")
    element.animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 1000);
else
    element.animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 1000);
```

To change background color, but comparision seems to fail, I also tried:

```
if (element.css("background-color")==rgb(0,0,0))
```

But the if condition seems to return false everytime?

Comment: try doing `console.log(element.css("background-color"));` to see what it is so you know what to compare it to

Comment: thanks, it prints rgb(0, 0, 0), changed it and works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the returned value is in rgb format, you should use quotation marks for strings:

```
if(element.css("background-color") == "rgb(0, 0, 0)")
```

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your browser, and what it supports.

Some browsers will return `rgb(0,0,0)`, but most newer browsers support rgba and return `rgba(0,0,0,0)`. Other browsers may return something completely different, who knows what?

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GMNV9/) and see if it will work, it works for me in newest Chrome, but it might not work in all browsers.

```
var element = $(this).parents("tr:first");

if (element.css("background-color")==="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
    element.animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 1000);
}else{
    element.animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 1000);
}
```

Also, your if/else statement was flawed, missing curlybrackets!

As it's not very reliable to check for colors returned from the browser, you should consider using a flag instead

```
var element = $(this).parents("tr:first");
var flag    = element.data("flag");

if ( flag ) {
    element.animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 1000);
}else {
    element.animate({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 1000);
}

element.data("flag", !flag);
```

Lastly, jQuery does not support animating colors without a plugin or jQuery UI.

Comment: what would be the safest way to go for major browsers

Comment: Use a class instead, and check for that class. Classes will work in all browsers. That's what I would do as checking rgb values are'nt very consistent, and script sensing browser support and converting color values are a little to complicated for something like this, in my opinion atleast.